# Is there $n\in\mathbb N$ for which $3n+1$ and $2n+1$ are perfect squares and $5n+3$ is a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Is there  $n\in\mathbb N$ for which $3n+1$ and $2n+1$ are perfect squares and $5n+3$ is prime?

My trying:
We know that $n=3n+1-(2n+1)$ is not prime.

But how it can help for $5n+3$?

$\mathbb N=\{1,2,...\}$.

Thank you!

Comment: How about sum of two perfect squares +1 ?

Comment: @Fawad It's obvious even for me!

Comment: is not a prime? or is a prime? what is the right statement

Comment: In general $4(2n+1)-3n-1=5n+3$

Comment: $2n+1$ is not a perfect square for $n=1$ , do you mean $3n+1$ **or** $2n+1$ is perfect square? Also you said in second comment,it's even , but 203 is odd :O

Comment: @kingW3 This pretty much solves it, you can turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take $2n+1=a^2$ and $3n+1=b^2$,WLOG assume $a,b>0$ then $4a^2-b^2=(2a-b)(2a+b)=5n+3$ this is prime only if $2a-b=1$ and $2a+b$ is prime.

Take $b=2a-1$ then $$3n+1=4a^2-4a+1\\3n=4(2n+1)-4\sqrt{2n+1}\\5n+4=4\sqrt{2n+1}\\25n^2+40n+16=16(2n+1)\\25n^2+8n=0$$so either $n=0$ or $n=-\frac{8}{25}$,but $0,-\frac{8}{25}\not\in \Bbb{N}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $2n+1=x^2$ and $3n+1=y^2.$ Then we have a [Pell-type Equation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1pZ2VkPTSAhWD44MKHbBrCnIQFggeMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmathworld.wolfram.com%2FPellEquation.html&usg=AFQjCNHiCgUVYpolIU3_y7aphx0JrHpdKw) $$3x^2-2y^2=1.$$ (You can transform this equation in to usual Pell format by multiplying $2$ or $3.$)

Solve this equation for the general solution of $n,$ then check $5n+3.$

Good Luck.

Comment: Are you sure that we can end the solution by this way?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I went back through my idea. It seems like you can achieve a final solution in this way. It all depends on the general solution of the Pell equation. However now I do not have enough time to post a complete solution. I will post it as soon as I can.